# Is it possible, using bootstrap 4 grid, to change the layout of my page for mobile in this specific way?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I currently have the following bootstrap grid set-up like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="A">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="B">
        B
      </div>
      <div class="C">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

And this produces something similar to this effect

[image]

I've been now trying to edit the bootstrap layout so that on a extra small screen the grid collapses to this

[image]

but I have been unsuccessful. Solutions I have tried are mainly around using the *Order* class but I can only switch the order between the two columns and not the 3 blocks individually. I have also tried splitting up the second column into separate rows but then *Order* seemed to only work within the columns. Is something like this possible within bootstrap grid or would I have to use flex classes?

Comment: I would use a single column and arrange A,B and C using the grid.

Comment: Another workaround could be: create two B items. Put one on top of A item and put another one on top of C item. In desktop show the one on top of C and in mobile show the one on top of A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custon class and display:contents could help for a few browsers:

example

```css
@media screen and (max-width:569px) {
  .d-sm-contents {
    display: contents
  }
  .order-top {
    order: -1;
  }
}

[class^="col"]>div {
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
      <div class="A">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 d-sm-contents">
      <div class="B col order-top">
        B
      </div>
      <div class="C col ">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this was awesome thanks, display: contents was exactly what I needed in my previous attempts

Answer (score 1):

See below. You need to see the page both in full and non-full size.

```css
.row > div {
  display: grid;
}

.A {
  order: 2;
}

.B {
  order: 1;
}

.C {
  order: 3;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .A {
    order: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 3;
  }
  
  .B {
    order: 2;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 2;
  }
  
  .C {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="A">
        A
      </div>
      <div class="B">
        B
      </div>
      <div class="C">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked really well. Ended up going with G-Cyrillus solution as the structure was similar to what I already had but this was a really good solution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tecnique:

```css
.A{ background-color:blue; height:100%}
.B{ background-color:red; }
.C{ background-color:yellow; }

div.row [class^="col"] {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="A">A</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="B">B</div>
            <div class="C">C</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! There was just another thing that was missing in this solution in that I needed the B block to be on top on small screens but I appreciate the input.